# How to force my system to see my hdd as 4096-byte?

Tags: veracrypt, sector-size

I'd like to create a VeraCrypt volume on my 4TB external hdd with 50GB of outer volume and the rest hidden. However, during the set up process I get the following error message:

[image: Error screenshot]

I don't want to divide it into two partitions, so I checked `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc` to find out about the sector size:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.7 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 57DF69GQ-C896-R557-EE98-54GF68GF7898

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.7T Linux filesystem
```

How do I force my system to see the hdd as 4096?

Answer (score 1):

Your drive is already using 4096 byte sectors. It's a function of the hardware.

It's asking you to create a smaller hidden volume, but you've already created a 3.7T partition. Make it less than 2T. Or... if you manually created that partition, let VeraCrypt create the partition for you.

See [here](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/encrypt-data-in-linux-with-veracrypt-an-alternative-to-truecrypt) for some instructions.

**Note**: Understand that encrypting your data can cause serious backup and restore issues if you have a drive failure.

Comment: It's a Seagate 4TB Expansion drive. Is there really no other way but to create a smaller (less than 2TB) partition? I'd like one encrypted 3.7T partition.

Comment: @JustCurious I don't know enough about VeraCrypt installs... but try removing your 3.7T partition, create a smaller 50G partition, and see if you get by your current error message, and see if VC prompts you to create another 3.2T encrypted partition. Knowing if that works should give you a clue want VC installation is asking for.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. Keep getting the same error message with a 50GB partition.

Comment: @JustCurious then I don't have any more ideas for you... sorry... somebody with more VC experience will have to chime in.